# GetModuleFileName always return lowercase in service

Tags: c++, windows, service, getmodulefilename

i need to get path to current executable in service, but when using GetModuleFileNameW or global variable _pgmptr i always get lowercase path, which is incorrect for me.

example: original path is C:/MyApp/app.exe and GetModuleFileNameW  always returns c:/myapp/app.exe

problem doesnt occur in desktop applications, only services.
how can i get the correct case path?

Comment: Why is it "incorrect" for you? Filenames and paths are seldom case sensitive in Windows.

Comment: That probably has something to do with the way you registered the service.  Try QueryFullProcessImageName() instead.

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName is not working, i forgot to say i use windows XP. my program is mostly a linux port, so these two paths are different for me

Comment: Are you comparing the string you get from `GetModuleFileNameW` with some other string? Where do you get the other string from? Maybe you should conform to the platform you're running on and use case-insensitive compare? And what is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? (Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: ive already solved it, i split path into separate folders and add them to list then iterate over parent directory of each folder in list to get correct values. i think thats the only solution, its working so ill leave it like that